# How to template cell in igxGrid?

Tags: angular, infragistics, ignite-ui-angular, igx-grid

I am starting to work with igx-grid and I have templated cells with combobox as below:

```html
<igx-column field="Locations" header="Available At" [editable]="true" [filterable]="false" width="220px">
     <ng-template igxCellEditor let-cell="cell" let-value>
         <igx-combo type="line"
                    [ngModel]="cell.value"
                    (ngModelChange)="onChange($event, cell)"
                    [displayKey]="'shop'"
                    [data]="locations"
                    width="220px"></igx-combo>
     </ng-template>
</igx-column>
```

However, when the cell is not in edit mode the combobox is not visible. How do I make the combo visible?

Answer (score 2):

You added cell editing template. In similar way you may add cell template. In your cell template you may add literally everything. To add drop down arrow you may add `igxIcon` like this:

```html
<ng-template igxCell let-cell="cell">
    <span>{{ cell.value }}</span>
    <igx-icon>keyboard_arrow_down</igx-icon>
</ng-template>
```

More about cell templates you may find [here](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/grid/grid#cell-template).
Note you will need to style this in order to force drop down arrow to be placed exactly where the one of the combo is.